# thymeleaf code completion not working intellij 14

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, thymeleaf, intellij-14

I am trying to use thymeleaf template engine with Spring MVC with intellij 14, but code completion is not working. please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Spring Core Online Tutorial</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

  <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
        rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"
          th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>

  <link href="../static/css/spring-core.css"
        th:href="@{css/spring-core.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <h2>This is my Thymeleaf index page. This is my changed.</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

There is complete support for thymleaf from intellj idea 14. Your missing part here is the use of namespace

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

use this in your template then you will get the intellij completion . Hope this answer your question. Thanks

Comment: It tooks me 1 day to realize why completion doesn't work in my project. I misspelled namespace name (```www.``` was missed). Thanks